# Trying to replicate Ubuntu AWS image on a laptop using Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtual-machines, docker

I have an Ubuntu server instance running some services in AWS, and I want to run the same setup on a dev machine (Mac). I have been trying to figure out a way, but running into some issues. I'll describe what I did and where I'm stuck, but please let me know if I went down the wrong path, and there's another easier way to do it.

I took a tarball of the whole EBS Volume snapshot (by mounting it as a second volume to a temporary EC2 instance). I then downloaded the tarball to my mac, and imported it as a Docker image:

```
docker import ~/Downloads/server.tar.gz
```

Now I can start a docker container using

```
docker run -i -t 9a842a29 /bin/bash
```

But the docker container can't start my services. They don't even show up under `service --status-all`.

When researching, I found that there's some issue with Docker and systemctl, which I used to install the services. Running `systemctl` gives the error message:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

I tried to hack around this by using https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement, but I don't see any improvement: my services are not found, even though the `.service` files are present in `/lib/systemd/system/`.

There's some discussion on AWS about exporting AMIs as VMs, but from what I understand that only works for AMIs that were imported VMs in the first place.

Is there a way to get my services to run under Docker? Or is there another way to virtualize my AMI or my tarball?

Comment: Why don't you just install from a standard Ubuntu image? They should be very very similar. Why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Tim I had installed and configured some specific software to run on the EC2 instance. It takes a bunch of steps to configure. I want to replicate my current setup, not just plain Ubuntu.

Comment: I'd install Ubuntu, configure locally, then move the config over.

Comment: Install a new system & copy configuration files.

Comment: I have to say, I'm perplexed by the responses so far. Do you guys really think that rebuilding an environment is always preferable/easier than cloning it? Am I missing something obvious about identifying all the files that were created by the multiple thirdparty applications that I've configured? How would I identify all the configuration and data files on the file system? I have no idea where apt-get install and the applications themselves put all their stuff...